# Formatar data no Angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-6

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário no qual é exigido a data de nascimento:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Data Nascimento</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Insira Data" class="form-control" id="dataNascimento" required [(ngModel)]="user.dataNascimento" name="dataNascimento" bsDatepicker>
</div>
```

Estou usando a biblioteca **bsDatepicker** para Criar um calendario.

**Imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na listagem aparece um formato estranho: 2018-12-07T05:00:00.000Z o errr data invalida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**User.ts**

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    nome: string;
    email: string;
    sexo:string;
    nacionalidade: string;
    naturalidade: string;
    cpf: string;
    dataNascimento: string;
}
```

Comment: bsDatepicker precisa mudar para pt-BR se eu não me engano ... está no formato americano

Comment: Em qual parte do codigo altero isso ?

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales dá uma lida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) para formatar datas, no seu exemplo pode ficar assim:

```
[(ngModel)]="user.dataNascimento | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'"
```

Claro que isso é um exemplo, o formato da data é você que decide.

Comment: Nesse exemplo deu erro...Acredito que tenha importa-lo ao projeto. De que forma posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Julio Neto, a data que estou gravando é essa: dataNascimento":"2012-12-01T04:00:00.000Z" na hora de lista esta vindo Invalid date

Comment: Entendi, o componente não está gravando uma string, mas um objeto do tipo Date, por isso quando você copia para o seu campo dataNascimento que é uma string, ele copia usando um formato padrão de data do javascript.

Comment: Por isso é sempre importante ler atentamente a documentação dos componentes que você usa. Infelizmente nunca trabalhei com esse componente em específico.